# Question about java ByteArrayInputStream Test : No Line Found

Tags: java, unit-testing, bytearrayinputstream

I am working on unit testing a Java application, and I am facing an issue with handling System.in for testing exception scenarios. My tests are designed to check if the application throws the correct exception when invalid input is provided.

Here is the code for initializing and restoring the System.in stream, and a couple of test cases:

```java
    public class RacingGameTest {
        private InputStream originalInputStream = System.in;

        void initializeStreams(String inputKey) {
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputKey.getBytes());
            System.setIn(byteArrayInputStream);
        }

        @AfterEach
        void restoreStreams() {
            System.setIn(originalInputStream);
        }

        @Test
        void 입력이_공백일_때_IllegalBlankException_던지기() {
            // Given
            final String ONLY_BLANK = " ";

            // When
            initializeStreams(ONLY_BLANK);

            // Then
            Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(racingGame::start).isInstanceOf(IllegalBlankException.class);
        }

        @Test
        void 이름이_누락되었을_때_IllegalBlankException_던지기() {
            // Given
            final String STRING_NAMES_CONTAIN_SPACE = "name1, ,name3";

            // When
            initializeStreams(STRING_NAMES_CONTAIN_SPACE);

            // Then
            Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(racingGame::start).isInstanceOf(IllegalBlankException.class);
        }
    }
```

In the first test, I am checking if IllegalBlankException is thrown when the input is a blank string. In the second test, I am verifying if IllegalBlankException is thrown when a name is missing.

When I run these tests individually, they pass. However, when I run all the tests in the class together, I face issues with System.in not being reset properly, resulting in java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found for tests that run after the first one.

I have used @AfterEach to restore System.in after each test, but it seems like it's not working as expected. Am I missing something? How can I ensure that System.in is properly reset after each test?

Comment: I wouldn't uses System.in at all. It would probably be better to make the input Stream configurable and then only use System.in for "production" while for tests you use the ByteArrayInputStream. Hard to help more without seeing the rest of the code though.

Comment: Are you reading from System.in directly? Or are you using a `Scanner`? When you use a `Scanner`: do you create a new `Scanner` every time you change System.in? Because `new Scanner(System.in)` stores a reference to the current System.in InputStream when you create it. Changing System.in to a new InputStream doesn't change the input stream that the previously created Scanner uses!

Comment: Is it due to `@AfterEach`. Should you be using `@AfterAll` instead?

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal example which reproduces the problem.